# Need help setting up scaffolding for this situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

[I asked a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354900/use-references-for-multiple-items-of-same-type), and got an excellent response, but, being a newbie to Rails and still getting the basics down, I need someone to show me how to set up some scaffolding for the situation that Hates_ was nice enough to outline for me. I've set up my application and whatnot, but I basically want to have, for example purposes:

- A "Stories" table, for a list of stories
- A "Pages" table, for a list of pages that can be attached to stories
- A "LinkedPages" table, to link one page to multiple other pages

The idea is that users can create Stories. Stories have Pages. Pages link to other Pages in a branching sort of way, and Hates_ suggested using a LinkedPages table to assist the process of determining which pages link to which other pages.

If someone could use the example models Hates_ provided on the link above (or give me better ones if needed), and just show me how to get this started, I'd be extremely grateful. Rails has had the highest initial learning curve of any programming or scripting language I've learned in the past, I'm just starting to understand many of the basics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated fast paced video that quickly presents some of the wicked sweet features in Rails via a somewhat contrived Blog tutorial.

http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov

The presenter crams a lot of information into a very short time frame and does paste in some prepared code from time to time, but over all he hits on many of the key features.

He explains how to set up scaffolding as well in about probably the last 5 mins or so.

Comment: I was hoping for some more specific help, but whatever. I'll just figure it out myself. Thanks, though.